# How do I catch more than one exception type?

Tags: php, exception, guzzle

I have the following code -

```
public function getPosts($limit = 25, $author = null) {

    try {

    } catch(\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
        return [];
    }

    return [];
}
```

I added this b/c when the page 404s I get the `ClientException`, however if the server returns a 500 error I get a `ServerException` - I tried just replacing this with `catch(Exception $ex)`, but I still get the unhandled/uncaught exception error.

Answer (score 3):

You can have multiple catch blocks for different exception types in php:

```
  try {

    } catch(\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
        return [];
    } catch(\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ServerException  $e) {
       //handle it...
 }
```

However, the assuming the Guzzle exceptions extend the general php `Exception` class (which of course they do), changing it to just  `Exception $e` should work.  Are you sure this is where the exception is being thrown?

On the guzzle site http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#exceptions you can see `GuzzleHttp\Exception\TransferException` base for all the client/server extensions, so you could just try to catch a `GuzzleHttp\Exception\TransferException`;

Comment: Thanks - I just checked elsewhere and I had another place that was using using GuzzleHttp without catching the exceptions - Replacing it with just `Exception $e` worked.

Comment: @5SK5  I generally recommend using the most granular exception reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

just list multiple catches:

```
try {
   ...
} catch (FooException e) {
   ...
} catch (BarException e) {
   ...
} catch (Exception e) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The catch can be chained one after the other  for handling multiple Error Types.

```
public function getPosts($limit = 25, $author = null) {

    try {

    } catch(\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
        return [];
    } catch(\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ServerException $e) {
        return [];
    }

    return [];
}
```

Comment: It will be better if you provide more details. At least use the Exceptions in the OP's question and don't forget the root namespace (leading backslash ) !

Answer (score 0):

Just keep catching

```
public function getPosts($limit = 25, $author = null) {

    try {

    } catch(\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
        return [];
    } catch (ServerException) {
        //some code
    }

    return [];
}
```

be aware of namespaces, if you try to catch Exception it will catch all exceptions, if it did not, maybe you didnt include the exception as use Exception or tried to catch \Exception